# How to sort json array by date value dd/mm/yyyy to update React state

Tags: reactjs, sorting

I am able to display the json array, but not the sorted version of it. It needs to be sorted  so that the newer one comes first according to the date_posted field which is in the format of **dd/mm/yyyy**

```
[
  {
    "id": "5537a23050b2c722f390ab60",
    "thumbImage": "http://lorempixel.com/175/115",
    "title": "reprehenderit nisi occaecat magna eiusmod officia qui do est culpa",
    "date_posted": "19/04/2020"
    ]
  }
]
```

...

```
useEffect(() => {
fetch("http://localhost:3000/items")
  .then((response) => response.json())
  .then((json) => {
    setAllItems(json);
    console.log(json);
  })
  .catch((err) => {
    console.log(`Error ${err}`);
  });
  }, []);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
allItems.sort((a, b) => {
a = a.date_posted.split('/');
b = b.date_posted.split('/');
return a[2] - b[2] || a[1] - b[1] || a[0] - b[0];
})
```

Comment: This method doesn't work because looks like it sorts by mm/dd/yyyy format. I need to sort in the format of DD/MM/YYYY

Comment: @ApexCowboy updated my answer

Comment: The newer one should come first instead, but the concept is good - solved. thanks.